# Formatting a Log File using Perl

Tags: regex, perl, file-io, substitution

I have a file which contains logs in a formatt, which can't be fixed from machine side  by increasing the page width. The only option that is left is collect it in a file and edit the file.

```
cat failure.txt

04-05-22 12:57:38 \GINGER.$VOLS01   COBULED.ROM.H01       005056  LDEV 0222 File
                                    $VOLS01.STEPHAN.TABLED, has been stopped 
                                    due to a processing error.
04-05-22 12:57:39 \GINGER.$VOLS02   COBULED.ROM.H01       005056  LDEV 0221 File
                                    $VOLS02.STEPHAN.TABLED, has been altered 
                                    due to a processing error.
04-05-22 12:57:40 \GINGER.$VOLS08   COBULED.ROM.H01       005056  LDEV 0216 File
                                    $VOLS08.STEPHAN.TABLED, has been rolled back 
                                    due to a processing error.
```

I wrote a simple perl program

```
    open $read_failed_log, '<', failure.txt or die "Could not open due to $!";

    open $write_failed_log, '>', failure_formated or die "Could not open due to $!";


    while($x = <$read_failed_log>){

        if(grep /^\S/,$x){
            print $write_failed_log "\n";                 
            print $write_failed_log $x;
            }else{
                print $write_failed_log $x;
            }
            }


    close $read_failed_log;
    close $write_failed_log;
```

But this does not give the desired output which is as follows:
Desired Output:

```
cat failure_formated.txt

04-05-22 12:57:38 \GINGER.$VOLS01   COBULED.ROM.H01       005056  LDEV 0222 File $VOLS01.STEPHAN.TABLED, has been stopped due to a processing error.
04-05-22 12:57:39 \GINGER.$VOLS02   COBULED.ROM.H01       005056  LDEV 0221 File $VOLS02.STEPHAN.TABLED, has been altered due to a processing error.
04-05-22 12:57:40 \GINGER.$VOLS08   COBULED.ROM.H01       005056  LDEV 0216 File $VOLS08.STEPHAN.TABLED, has been rolled back due to a processing error.
```

Generally what is needed is the log lines should not break. Each log entry would be in one line as the failure_formated.txt shows above.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're still getting line breaks, yes? Have you tried using `chomp $x;` to remove newlines?

Comment: don't you just need a `chomp $x` in there somewhere?

Comment: Thanks .. Yes.. it works now ...after adding chomp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It chomps new line, and puts one at the beginning of the line when it starts with digit.

```
while (my $x = <$read_failed_log>) {
    chomp($x);
    $x =~ s/^(?=\d)/\n/;
    print $write_failed_log $x;
}
```

one-liner,

```
perl -pe 'chomp; s/^(?=\d)/\n/' failure.txt > failure_formated
```

Comment: Yes Now it has now one problem... There are huge spaces ... where there was break.. Added $x =~ s/\s{3,}/\s/gm; after it.. now it works fine..

Answer (score 0):

The `chomp` fixes your line returns, but you have a large number of spaces between two of the fields so they are wrapping around.  Try trimming parts of the string (see .e.g below)

```
open $read_failed_log, '<', "failure.txt" or die "Could not open: $!";       
open $write_failed_log, '>', "failure_formated" or die "Could not open:  $!";

while(my $x = <$read_failed_log>){  
    chomp $x;           # chomp the lines being read
    $x =~ s/ {35}//gm;  # remove blocks of > 35 white spaces
    if(grep /^\S/,$x){ 
        print $write_failed_log "\n";
        print $write_failed_log $x;      
        }
        else
        {                                                                     
            print $write_failed_log $x;                                         
        }                                                                       
}                                                                       

close $read_failed_log;                                                         
close $write_failed_log;
```

Cleaning the data file this way before parsing/printing it might be a job for a one liner (see @mpapec's answer for a tip). Hope that helps.